# Why is Kubernetes namespace in a limbo state?

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I've manually deleted `argocd` namespace. Sure enough, `kubectl get ns` doesn't list it anymore. Why then does `kubectl get -n argocd application` still succeed?

```
NAME      SYNC STATUS   HEALTH STATUS
grafana   OutOfSync     Missing
```

(Some `Application`s are also listed as `Healthy` or `Progressing`.)

The actual issue is that `metadata.finalizers`, on each `Application`, is blocking its removal. I *can* manually delete each `Application`'s `metadata.finalizers` (which does get the `Application` deleted). Yet, why then doesn't the following work as well?

```
kubectl patch -n argocd application grafana  -p '[ { "op": "remove", "path": "/metadata/finalizers" } ]' --type=json
Error from server (NotFound): namespaces "argocd" not found
```

Applications (`application.argoproj.io/<app-name>`) are the only resources returned by

```
kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name \
  | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -n argocd
```

Comment: Are all resources in the namespace deleted or is there anything in the namespace left?

Comment: @dan1stisonstrike, the only resources left are the Applications (the example `grafana` and 13 more), as shown by the `kubectl api-resources` command added to the question.

Comment: Did you try to _delete_ these applications (instead of just removing the metadata)?

Comment: @dan1stisonstrike, I did, via `kubectl delete -nargocd application.argoproj.io/grafana`. Alas, the command would hang and the app not get deleted (presumably due to `finalizers`?).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that some pods of the deleted namespace stayed stuck on termination state, you can run this:

```
for p in $(kubectl get pods | grep Terminating | awk '{print $1}'); do kubectl patch pod $p -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}' ;done
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `kubectl get pods -n argocd` returns:                                 
"No resources found in argocd namespace."

Comment: what if they miss the link to the namespace ? if you try without passing the namespace, what happens ?

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Similar return: "No resources found in default namespace."

Comment: do you get something checking the status with: kubectl get ns argocd -o yaml

Comment: Just an error, as in the question: `namespaces "argocd" not found`